# Merge two sorted lists in Haskell- what is the difference between these Algorithms

Tags: list, haskell, merge, sorting, sortedlist

I try to understand, what's the difference between the second two algorithms.

The first one (merge) works well, but when I try to convert the algorithm to Guarded notation (merge') I get a "Non-exhaustive patterns ..." exception.

But why is the third version (merge'') working? It is almost the same like merge', there has to be something with the list (x:xs) that I don't understand.

```
   1 -- merges two sortedists                                        
   2 merge xs [] = xs
   3 merge [] ys = ys
   4 merge (x:xs) ys
   5     | x <= head ys = x : (merge xs ys)
   6     | otherwise = head ys : (merge (x:xs) (tail ys))
   7     
   8 -- merges two sorted lists (fails with exception)
   9 merge' z@(x:xs) ys
  10     | ys == [] = z
  11     | z == []  = ys
  12     | x <= head ys = x : (merge' xs ys)
  13     | otherwise = head ys : (merge' (x:xs) (tail ys))
  14     
  15 
  16 -- merges two sorted lists (exept the last element of the first list)
  17 merge'' z@(x:xs) ys
  18     | ys == [] = z
  19     | xs == []  = ys
  20     | x <= head ys = x : (merge'' xs ys)
  21     | otherwise = head ys : (merge'' (x:xs) (tail ys))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `merge'` and `merge''` you assume the first argument to be of the form `x:xs`, this excludes the empty list, and is causing the problems.

For example

```
head z@(x:xs) = x
```

will produce `1` as expected when calling `head([1,2,3])`, but `head([])` will throw a `Non-exhaustive patterns in function head` exception because `[]` does not match `x:xs` (the `@` is not really important here).

In particular, this means that in `merge'` the `z == []` case can never be matched and also `merge''` will throw an exception if you call `merge [] [1,2,3]` for example.

Also note that in `merge''` the case `xs == []` is problematic. If, for example, we call `merge'' [1] [2]`, then this case is matched because `[1]` is `1:[]`. Then, just `ys`, i.e., `[2]` is returned and the `x`, which is `1`, gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the last two solutions is that `merge'` has a dead branch `z == []` - this condition will never hold, given that `z@(x:xs)`.

The version `merge''` works by mistake - it will break if you try some other inputs, where at some point `z==[]`.